EPERM on using network sockets via apache commons net ftp
I am importing the apache commons net ftp client
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient

And I try and execute the ftp.connect() function
    val ftp = FTPClient()
    ftp.connect(localAddress, port)
    Log.w("FTP", "connected")

The ftp.connect() results in a long stacktrace exception.
But mainly it is this line that seems to be the issue:
 Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

And so I have added to my manifest:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

But the error still persists.
I had read the documentation for these permissions:
https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/network-ops/connecting
And it seems that I have done all that I need to do but I still keep getting the EPERM Operation not permitted error.
Any help and guidance would be appreciated, and I am just new to this so maybe I am missing something simple.
My app target device is on Android 13.

The resolution seems to me relies on a couple of points:

Put the appropriate uses-permission in the manifest. There is no need to ask for it at run-time.

Make sure a listener is available at the server side.

Android requires the ftp.connect run on a separate thread separate to the main thread. For me the following worked:
 suspend fun networkReq() =
     withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

         val ftp = FTPClient()
         try {
             ftp.connect(server_ip, server_port)
         } catch (e: Exception) {
             e.printStackTrace()
         }
         Log.w("FTP", "connected")

     }


 lifecycleScope.launch {
     launch {
         networkReq()
     }
 }



